emulator (genymotion, bluestack and android studio) not working
I am currently programming a very simple app. I used to test it on an virtual android phone with Android Studio Emulator. This worked very good for a long time. Then it started to terminate and I could not fix it. I tried multiple ways nothing helped. Therefore I completely set up my Windows system freshly from a boot stick. Installed Android Studio and did nothing else. Still not working. I then tried genymotion. It wont even start the application at all. I can see nothing in the task manager. Fixing issues here also did not help and Oracle seemed fine. Lastly I tried BlueStack which is also not even starting the application like I never clicked on it.
HyperV is not active and since this laptop used to run emulators without a problem I guess it can not be the hardware.
I have no antivirus system installed at the moment and freshly installed windows without any special adjustments.
My system is:
AMD Ryzen 7 5700U with Radeon Graphics            1.80 GHz
RAM: 16,0 GB (13,9 GB usable)
Windows 11 Education
23H2
22631.3880
I am working on this problem now one week and do not have a clue where the problem is and as a newbie am totally lost.
I would be immensely grateful for help and provide any other needed information.
Error which occured in Android studio looked like this: Android Emulator issues in new versions - The emulator process has terminated
